# deques slowes program if if not used?

Tags: c++, performance, size, deque

So I have this deque

```
deque <int> a[1001];
```

And a simply add elements by using

```
a[i].push_back(val);
```

And erase them using

```
a[i].pop_front();
```

If I use `a[1001]` it works great, if I use `a[10001]` it takes a few seconds and if I use `a[100001]` it takes something like 30seconds to execute the program.

The thing is that in every case I only push_back like 5 vals, the only difference is the size of the deque.

Why's that?

I only need to erase elements from the front, is there a better way? :D

Oh and also, how many bytes does a push_backed element use?:D (in this type of deque)

Comment: `deque` is the right structure, whether you access the first deque or the 10000th, the time should be the same, within an instance of the deque, operations of course depend on how many entries there are - are you sure that the time is taken by the pop and push operations?

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to accomplish here? 100001 deques is insane!

Comment: I have 100.001 different keys, and for each key I have to add and erase values. Do you have a better solution? ;\

Comment: Cristy: It sounds tough to keep all these keys in memory - try using a database instead - maybe sqlite3?

Comment: Side note, compiling and running in Debug mode it will be much slower than in Release.

Comment: By the way, I would suggest using std::list instead of std::deque in this case - it has less memory overhead if you only do like 5 push_backs.

Comment: The program MUST be done in C++ only. Is there something better then deques for this?

Comment: Sqlite is an embeddable database, you could load the library tell it to make an in memory table then store your data.

Comment: Cristy: There is no problem making a single executable with sqlite3 - it's quite easy to embed it - and it makes sense for handling lots of data like this.

Comment: Ok, I kinda' solved it. I only need push_back and pop_front, so that's exactly what a queue does, so I'll use queues instead of queues. And also, I've created a vector of queues so I'll only use as many as I need :D

Answer (score 3):

```
deque<int> a[1001];
```

It's not a deque of size 1001, it's rather 1001 deques, each must be initialized and destructed, hence the slowness. You create a deque like this:

```
deque<int> a;
a.push_back(2);
a.push_back(3);
a.push_back(5);
a.push_back(7);
a.pop_back(); // ...
```

Comment: That's what I need, 1001 deques... So, what's the best way I can create 100 001 deques (or anything that will allow me to erase_front). I think I should create a vector of deques, so it only uses as many as the program needs?

Comment: Then I don't understand your complains. Yes, doing something N times takes O(N) time. In your case you create N deques, so it takes O(N) time. If you *really* need more than one deque (that I doubt) then yes, create exactly the number that you need.